# All Possible Notations of Simple Quadrilaterals Using Permutations

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Let $\square ABCD$ be a simple quadrilateral. Now there are many ways to represent the same quadrilateral, such as $\square BCDA$ or $\square ADCB$. These notations can be described by permutations; for example, the following permutation will correspond to $\square BCDA$.
$$\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}A & B & C & D \\ B & C & D & A\end{pmatrix}$$
However, $\square ABDC$ is not equal to $\square ABCD$, since the sides are not equal.

What I want to do is to find all the possible notations for $\square ABCD$. I've worked my way in proving that $\square ADCB$ is indeed equal to $\square ABCD$, and I want to prove that "pushing" the vertices leads to the same quadrilateral. In other words, for $P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4\in\{A,B,C,D\}$, $\square \sigma(P_1)\sigma(P_2)\sigma(P_3)\sigma(P_4)$ is equal to $\square P_1P_2P_3P_4$. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have all circular permutations of $ABCD$

$\begin{array}{}
A&B&C&D\\
&B&C&D&A\\
&&C&D&A&B\\
&&&D&A&B&C\\
\end{array}$

Similarly when the polygon is walked in reverse orientation, circular permutations of $DCBA$.

$\begin{array}{}
D&C&B&A\\
&C&B&A&D\\
&&B&A&D&C\\
&&&A&D&C&B\\
\end{array}$

So in cycle notations these are $(ABCD)$ and $(DCBA)$.